# Python regular expression to modify paths

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace some paths in XML files with my string.

All of the paths to change start with either `schemaLocation=` or `location=`, followed by path and filename with extension.

Some examples:

```
FROM

   'schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2.xsd"/>' (1)
    or
    'schemaLocation=
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2.xsd"/>' (2)
    or 
    'schemaLocation="b-2.xsd"/>' (3)

TO

    'schemaLocation="b-2.xsd"/>' (4)  in this sample new path is clear
     or 
    'schemaLocation="../xsd/b-2.xsd"/>' (5) where "../xsd/" is new path
```

I wrote

```
regex = '(?<=schemaLocation=)([\s]*[\r\n]*[\s]*".*[/]?)(?=.+[.]xsd["])'
```

But I can't modify it to process from (3) to (5).

Comment: is the strings below TO are your expected results?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, yes this is expected results

Comment: @Dcow you mean this http://regex101.com/r/wB1qU1/6 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I need to save old filenames and only modify paths

Comment: Don't forget to quote backslashes in ordinary string expressions. `\s` should be `\\s`. You got away with it this time because `\s` has no special meaning, but it will usually bite you. There are also [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), which are better when you don't need to include control characters (as you do in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
(schemaLocation=)\s*\"(.*\/)?(.*\")(.*)
```

Replacement string:

```
\1"\3\4
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wB1qU1/7)

**Example:**

```
>>> s = """schemaLocation=
...             "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2.xsd"/>"""
>>> re.sub(r'(schemaLocation=)\s*\"(.*\/)?(.*\")(.*)', r'\1"\3\4', s, re.M)
'schemaLocation="b-2.xsd"/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the original text is XML does not seem to play a role here.
You could use a rather nice feature of re.sub, namely the ability to pass a
function to compute the replacement string.
For instance:

```
import re
text = "...."   # your text
r = re.compile('(schemaLocation=")([^"]+)"')

def repl(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(2) == 'types.xsd':
       s = '../xsd/b-2.xsd'
    else:
       s = '...'  # other cases
    return matchobj.group(1) + s


out = r.sub(repl, text)
```